# NHibernate - see SQL without all the other guff

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

So I'm using log4net to write log output to the trace. Show sql is specified in the configuration file. I seem to have to set the log output level to DEBUG to get the SQL output, but DEBUG also produces pages and pages of other guff I have to scroll past.

Can I get the SQL without the guff?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a logger for `NHibernate.SQL` in the `log4net` config block, like so:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

With the appender-config

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

(replace this with whatever you prefer, like `rollingFileAppender`)

Another option is using a tool like [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/).

Comment: I already had an appender, so I just added the logger element and set its appender-ref ref attribute to the name of the appender.